# Script all tables in database

Tags: sql-server

I have database that has 1000+ tables.

I just want the structure of the database (Create Table script)

I can do it one by one but that will take long time.

Is there anyway to extract the script of all tables at once (no data needed)

My database is SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use SSMS, right click your database, and them select tasks, in the list, select generate scripts, following the steps, select specific database objects, which allow you check tables checkbox. After keep going, you will get the scripts for all tables.